# Cannot link streams code with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc4, gcc3

I have a problem compiling the following code:

```
// writing on a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return 0;
}
```

To compile:

```
g++ -c -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused -fexceptions  -I. -I../../../stub -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -I.  -o t.o ./test.cc

g++ -o t -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused -fexceptions -Wl,-brtl -Wl,-blibpath:/lib:/usr/lib t.o -lpthreads
```

The compile gives some warnings:

```
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .__divdi3
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .__moddi3
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .__udivdi3
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .__umoddi3
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .__udivmoddi4
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

The resulting binary appears to execute OK:

```
$ ./t
$ echo $?
0
```

The output file is created but empty !?!

I would be *VERY* grateful for any pointers as to what the problem might be.

Comment: Does it work, if you compile it `g++ test.cc -o test.run`?

Comment: Take out the unused libraries exceptions, and you aren't using any threads so why are you compiling with the thread flags ?

Comment: I would try isolating the compiler and linker options. Your program works fine for me without all those extra options.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it is a library problem. Clearing libpath did the trick, and the program worked.

Answer (score 1):

Libpath was set incorrectly, causing the problem. The correct setting should be

LIBPATH=/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/